# dhtmlxChart line with one point build

Tags: charts, dhtmlx

I am using a line type of dhtmlxChart in my app. It works ok, but when I have only one point it doesn't show on the chart.
The structure for the chart is:

```
{data:[{id:1,value_y:1.046000,value_x:1,lo_limit:1.000000,up_limit:10.000000,type:"all"}]}
```

Why I can’t see the line of chart?

Answer (score 0):

Line chart need for building 2 points minimum to connect them via line